# Excel VBA Macro - Copy method of range class failed & Insert method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro to copy and insert rows or columns in different locations depending on an input string. The copy and insert locations are defined by Named Ranges within the spreadsheet.

If I want to add several columns in the same section, everything works great. If I add even one column in one section, then want to add a column in another section, I get one of two errors: *Copy method of Range class failed* OR *Insert method of Range class failed*

I haven't been able to figure out why sometimes the copy method throws an error and sometimes it doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
    Sheets("TL Master").Range("Insert" & strAddType).Copy

        'Offset for row/column
        If strRowColumn = "row" Then
            'Row = add value above
            Range("Insert" & strAddType).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("Add" & strAddType & "ButtonCell").Offset(-4, 0).Value = strNewName
        Else
            'Column = add value left
            Sheets("TL Master").Range("Insert" & strAddType).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Range("Add" & strAddType & "ButtonCell").Offset(0, -4).Value = strNewName
            If strAddType = "Machine" Then Range("Add" & strAddType & "ButtonCell").Offset(0, -4).Interior.Color = clrComplexityColor

        End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You code is missing the sheet name. For example -

```
Sheets("TL Master").Range("Insert" & strAddType).Copy

    'Offset for row/column
    If strRowColumn = "row" Then
        'Row = add value above
        Sheets("TL Master").Range("Insert" & strAddType).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("TL Master").Range("Add" & strAddType & "ButtonCell").Offset(-4, 0).Value = strNewName
    Else
        'Column = add value left
        Sheets("TL Master").Range("Insert" & strAddType).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Sheets("TL Master").Range("Add" & strAddType & "ButtonCell").Offset(0, -4).Value = strNewName
        If strAddType = "Machine" Then Range("Add" & strAddType & "ButtonCell").Offset(0, -4).Interior.Color = clrComplexityColor

    End If
```

The other thing I would make note of is if your Offset forces data to be pasted outside of the sheet this will cause an error. For example, if your named range is A1:A10 and you do and Offset(0, -1) this is off the sheet and causes an error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or if you wont write sheet name so many times you can use With instruction.
That will be:
`With Sheets("TL Master")`  
`If...Then`  
`.Range("insert"...)...`  
`Else...`  
`End If...`  
`End With...`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I still receive the same errors. I am also getting a new error periodically. **Automation error The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.**

Comment: I looked into the possibility you mentioned about pasting outside of the sheet, and I didn't have any luck there either. As I mentioned in my original post, everything works when I open the sheet; I can add rows or columns in any one location. After I add my first row or column, I can continue adding more to the same section of the spreadsheet, using the same named range, but I get the error if I try adding to another section.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?